# Restore backup with SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, restore

When I attempt to restore the backup (.bak 1,32GO) database into SQL Server 2008 I get the following message:

> CREATE DATABASE or ALTER DATABASE failed because the cumulative size
>   of the resulting database will exceed the license limits of 4096 MB
>   per database

Comment: Buy a license that allows for a bigger DB or shrink your DB. Also, possibly try a different database technology that is cheaper or free.

Comment: That's the limit imposed upon SQL Server *Express*, is that what your restoring to?

Answer (score 0):

A backup is often significantly smaller than the space required for a live database, presumably the database the backup came from is over 4096Mb so sql cannot restore it. As per the comments, you'll need to get a new license to be able to restore this db.

Comment: But the size of my database is only 1.32G

Comment: If the size of the .bak file is 1.32G, your database is likely much larger. If your database is 1.32G and your .bak file is smaller than that, then you perhaps have other databases already.